# Java. Object instance changes weirdly

Tags: java, arrays, object

```
class Test {
    static int p;
    Test(int x) {
        p=x;
    }
}

class Mtest
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Test c[] = new Test [100];
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            c[i]=new Test(i);
        }

        for (int i=0; i<5;i++) {
            System.out.println(c[i].p);         
        }
}
```

OUTPUT:
    4
    4
    4
    4
    4

What kind of sorcery is this? shouldnt it give me 0,1,2,3,4??

Comment: Remove the `static` keyword from declaration of `p`, and see the magic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using static field

```
static int p;
```

which is shared across class (not per instance)

if you want it per Object, remove `static` from declaration

Comment: There is only one `p` variable so it can have only one value, the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Because `p` is static, i.e. field of the class, not of an object. So `p` is shared between all instances of class `test`. You should remove `static` from field declaration to achieve your result expectations.

Answer (score 0):

You declared `p` as `static`. Remove it and it should word fine. Plus format your code following the java guidelines, it makes it much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Change `static int p;` to `int p` -> You're using class variables instead of instance variables.